# Is there a way to get x entries with offset of y entries with YouTube data API?

Tags: youtube-data-api

Now the documentation says that you can specify a URL parameter "maxResults" to set a cap from 0 to 50, but is there a way to specify an offset from the first entry?
I want to implement a search in my android app, and dynamic loading while scrolling would be nice.
Sadly I'm not sure if this part is documented somewhere else, or just not implemented.
Please let me know if you know.

Comment: I don't get why you need such offset mechanism as there is the pagination (see [`nextPageToken`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#nextPageToken)) one. If you really need it, it seems that if you decode the `pageToken` in base64 there is a binary encoding that may give this offset mechanism.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison, But that still leaves the limit of 50 entries at max, right?

Comment: Indeed it seems to.